# Set video embedded in page to autoplay or not, based on query string?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, vimeo, url-parameters

Is it possible to set a video embedded on a page to autoplay based on a query string on the URL of the page it's embedded on?

For instance, if I have a page at bla-blah.web/interthingy.html with a Vimeo embed, is it possible to make it so bla-blah.web/interthingy.html?play or bla-blah.web/interthingy.html?play=true so that the Vimeo embed contained within that page autoplays?

Basically something that reads the URL, and sets the embedded video to autoplay based on whether it has a specific query string.

My apologies if this has been asked and answered elsewhere; I can't seem to find anything on it.

Comment: Are you currently able to auto play the video?

Answer (score 1):

A solution can be based on the [window.location.search](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLHyperlinkElementUtils/search).

Using the [split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) and [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/it/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) it's possible to search the query parameter play and its value.

If this parameter exists and the value is not specified or true it's possible to [play](https://github.com/vimeo/player.js#play-promisevoid-passworderrorprivacyerrorerror) the Vimeo video:

```js
var playParams = window.location.search.split('&').filter(function(ele, index) {
  var tmpArr = ele.split('=');
  if (tmpArr[0] == '?play' || tmpArr[0] == 'play') {
    if (tmpArr.length == 2) {
      return tmpArr[1] == 'true';
    }
    return true;
  }
});

if (playParams.length > 0) {
  var iframe = document.querySelector('iframe');
  var player = new Vimeo.Player(iframe);

  player.play();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://player.vimeo.com/api/player.js"></script>



<iframe src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/76979871" width="640" height="360" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe>
```